# Which bias in a repeated measure setting: Use a regularized method or a mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, regularization

I have an observational study design with repeated measures on 27 patients with mean: 2.862 ± 1.36, median: 3 (IQR: 2 - 3) measurement per patient.

I initially set up a mixed model analysis (R `lme4::glmer()`) but I noticed that many predictor had infinite or zero estimates, typical of separation problems (which indeed there is in the data). I usually do regression analysis with Gelman's `arm::bayesglm()` with quasilikelihood link functions, which helps me fix these problems, but it doesn't perform mixed model analysis.

Therefore my doubt is: should I increase bias by ignoring the by patient grouping of the observations or loose estimates on some (actually strongly correlated) predictors?

**UPDATE:**
I found the blme package that does exactly what I need, that is bayesian regularized mixed model! Anyway I leave the question open for the sake of discussion of the problem from the theoretical point of view.